# Firefox blocks page loading due to CSP issues - Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, firefox, content-security-policy

I am trying to load the page from testing server where I deployed my app.
Internal url is something like this: https://172.31.11.137/plugin3000/dashboard
But when I go to the page it is completely blank and in dev console see the following error
This is quite strange and when I debug it in my local it doesnt show any of this error and page loads as expected without any error
I am using Angular 14 and use sock proxy in firefox to connect with internal server.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od6jW.png)

I updated the CSP meta tag but it is not helping anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a default CSP and then trying to add another policy in meta to fix the first. Adding another policy can only make it stricter, so you should try to modify the policy served in a response header.

Then your will need to rewrite the eval statements (https://web.dev/csp/#eval-too) or add 'unsafe-eval' to default-src or a script directive if you implement any. From your error messages it also seems like you need to allow other sources but it is not totally clear which sources are needed.

Comment: I added the following meta tag but it still not working : 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
          content="default-src https://172.31.13.121/plugin3000/* 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';img-src 'self' data:;
          font-src 'self' data:;style-src https://172.31.13.121/plugin3000/* 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:;
          script-src https://172.31.13.121/plugin3000/* 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">

And if I use a firefox extension laboratory and define the same policy then it works but that is not the solution for me.

Comment: As I already said, adding another policy (as you do in meta) can only make the total policy stricter. You will need to modify/remove the existing policy, likely served in a response header.